# Different user login problem because of the syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my program, I want different users to have different class_id in order to let them go into different mange page. I distribute them in 3 class id   1= manger 2= NormalUser 3 =admin but when I full outer join them I think the error is here. but i can't find it  can someone help?

the problem is in query

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
include("conn.php");
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $user=$_POST['username'];
        $pwd=$_POST['password'];
        $query="SELECT * 
            FROM employees 
            FULL OUTER JOIN admin 
                on employees.class_id=admin.class_id 
            WHERE (employees.employee_id='$user'&& employees.password='$pwd')
              ||(admin.username='$user' && admin.password='$pwd')";
        $data   = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $total  =mysqli_num_rows($data);
        $class = $data->fetch_assoc();
        if ($class['class_id']==2)
        {
            $_SESSION['employee_id']=$user;
            header('location:home.php');
        }
        elseif ($class['class_id']==1){
            $_SESSION['employee_id']=$user;
            header('location:manger/home.php');
        } 
        else {
            header('location:index.php');
       }
}

?>
```

Comment: _I think the error is here_

What error? Please, improve yuor post, format it nicely, and explain better what you're trying to achieve and the issue you're facing.
Thanks.

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL OUTER JOIN. Use UNION, ORDER BY and LIMIT 1.

Comment: **Don't store your passwords in plain-text!** This is not secure *at all!* PHP has built-in functions which you should use to handle storing of passwords, see the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which is a lot more secure!

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is here :

> use 'AND','OR' instead of &&,||

```
WHERE (employees.employee_id='$user' AND employees.password='$pwd')
OR (admin.username='$user' AND admin.password='$pwd')"
```